# Changing css class for responsive css

Tags: javascript, css

I need to make my changes only at my responsive css and I don't want it to affect my normal css? How can I do it with the codes.
Here is my js:

```
$("#open-button").click(function () {
    $('#additem').css({ 'margin-left': '10%' });
});
```

The below is my css and responsive css

```
/*normal css*/
#additem{
    margin-left:0;
}

/*responsive css*/
@media all and (max-width: 1366px) {
    #additem{
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want `'margin-left': '10%'` to be applied only in case of `max-width: 1366px`?

Comment: Yes! I want to keep my normal css.

Comment: I see no class in your css... instead of changing the style just change the class, define whatever you will for that class for your "responsive" CSS and just forget about it in the rest of your css...

Comment: Then see the answer by George, this is how it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

`.css()` changes the *inline* styles of an element - it does not know of, nor can it change media queries, since media queries cannot exist in an inline state.

Add a class rather than changing CSS. You can then apply margin to this class, within a specific media query:

**CSS**

```
/*normal css*/
#additem{
    margin-left:0;
}

/*responsive css*/
@media all and (max-width: 1366px) {
    #additem{
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    #additem.small-margin{
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#open-button").click(function () {
    $('#additem').addClass('small-margin');
});
```

Comment: Thank you @George ! But i wonder is that a way like (I am just asking):
$("#open-button").click(function () {
    $('#additem').css({'@media all and (max-width: 1366px) margin-left': '10%' });
});

Comment: Ah, you overtake me by few seconds ;P. Congratulations ;). BTW: You can look at my answer for documentation links and really useful toogleClass function. +1 from me.

Comment: @S.T. No. `.css()` changes inline styles and media queries cannot be inline.

Answer (score 0):

You should try not to edit css parameters inline with jquery. You can always use:

1. toogleClass(): http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/
2. addClass(): http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
3. removeClass(): http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

In that case you can prepare few additional classes in your CSS file, and make special rules for them using min and max width for devices.

And in the future if something is not OK, all you must modify is just CSS file, not jquery or javascript files. It is a good practice.

---

I think jQuery CSS and visibility functions are made only in case of calculations of width, padding, margins, and animations. And for example color loops.

**Simple css rules should be implemented using above functions, and not inputed directly in js file.**

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to use `matchMedia` to use media queries in your JS

```
$("#open-button").click(function () {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1366px)').matches) {
        $('#additem').css({ 'margin-left': '10%' });
    }
});
```